# Angular 5 - Issue while subscribing the Behavior Subject

Tags: rxjs, angular5, observable, behaviorsubject

I am facing issue while subscribing the behavior Subject variable in constructor of one service . Subscription happens for the first time when value of **ok is 0** but when i am doing .**next(1)** in **service 1** , the subscription is not happening in constructor of service 2 .

`Service 1 : Where behavior subject variable is emitting`

```
 counter: number = -1;
 ok: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  if (this.counter === 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.checkCounterFinally();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  checkCounterFinally() {
    if (this.counter === 0) {
      this.ok.next(1);

    }

  }
```

`Service 2: Where i am subscribing the behavior subject variable in constructor.`

```
constructor(private service: Service1){
    this.service.ok.subscribe((val) => {
      console.log("service2", val);
      if (val=== 1) {
        this.getDataFromLocalStorage();
      }

    });
}
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker with this with the minimum code possible? I think that the main issue is that you're using the subject directly instead of returning the observable (via `asObservable()`) but it's difficult to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The use of BehaviorSubject looks good. The source of your problem can be that there are many Service1 instance in your app.

Comment: Hi Mohamed , thanks for the reply . I did the same way for some functionality . it is working fine over there . Moreover , i have only instance of the service 1 here .

Answer (score 0):

You need to call next method from the component as below.

```
constructor(private service: Service) {
     this.service.checkCounterFinally(); 
   }
```

Change the service like this.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Service {
   counter: number = -1;
    ok: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);
    selectedSubjectObsv = this.ok.asObservable();

     constructor() { 
if (this.counter === 0) { 
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.checkCounterFinally();
      }, 1000);
    } 
  }


     checkCounterFinally() {
   // if (this.counter === 0) {
      this.ok.next(1);

   // }

  }
}
```

Find the working code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwt91u

Comment: Hi Supun , thanks for the reply . But unfortunately , as per requirement i dont have to use the component for the same . Its the communication between services only using behavior subject. Any suggestions.

Comment: I have used single component, only for the demo purpose. Still you can use multiple components. See the updated code in stackblitz.